# Why can't I use 我的 in Classical Chinese?

Tags: word, word-requests

***almost all words are stand alone in classical texts. Only modern Chinese tend to use multi characters to form a word.  Your examples would be 明身/明体， 明心. But  明我的心 is not a traditional way.***

Why can't 心 be modified with a adjective in Classical Chinese??

Comment: There isn't any 的 in classical Chinese, it is omitted or replaced with 之, and 之 is used usually nowadays in Mandarin. The word for **I/me** is different in different era, like 朕, 余/予, 吾.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't 心 be modified with a adjective in Classical Chinese?

Of course it can. In your case, 明吾心、明吾之心、明我心、明我之心 are all correct.

"的" is not common in classical texts, you can use "之" instead or just omit it.

Comment: In Modern Chinese, can I say 明我的心 or 明帅心 or明这心?

Comment: No, a single 明 is not a valid verb in mordern Chinese.

Comment: So, also from 见面, I can't use it into 见你的面 or 见帅面 or 见这面 in Modern Chinese?

Comment: From 操家, can't I use it in 操我的家 操这家 操多家 likewise in Modern Chinese?

Comment: @HarutoNagasaki, 明我的心 is ok, but not good as  明我之心. But 明帅心 or明这心 is not used.  操家 is not that common.

Comment: 明帅心, 明这心, 见帅面, 见这面, 操我的家, 操这家, 操多家 sounds awkward. You may use 见此一面 for 见这面. 操家 is a whole word, you may not add any part within the two characters.